# JQuery/Ajax Unexpected Identifier error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have no clue as to why I am getting this error, my JavaScript skills aren't very great but I know main basics, along with JQuery and Ajax, but I really can't see why I am getting the error "Unexpected Identifier" here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $("#GhostModMenu").hide();
    $("#GhostModMenu").draggable({ axis: "x" });
    $("#buttons").show();
    $("#show_self_menu").hide();
    $("#show_vip_menu").hide();
    $("#show_user_menu").hide();
    $("#show_staff_menu").hide();
    var open = false;

    $("#g5k").click(function()
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sfk.php", 
            data: $("#gfkf").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });

    $("#g5kp").click(function()
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sfk.php", 
            data: $("#gfkp").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });

    $("#toggle_frostbite").click(function()
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "gmmcp.php", 
            data: $("#give_frostbite_form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });

    $("#clear_self_chatlogs_button").click(function()
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "gmmcp.php", 
            data: $("#clear_self_chatlogs_form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });

    $("#give_self_vip_button").click(function()
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "gmmcp.php", 
            data: $("#give_self_vip_form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });

    $("#give_self_rank_button").click(function()
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "gmmcp.php", 
            data: $("#give_self_rank_form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });

    $("#option_back_button").click(function()
    {

        $("#buttons").show();
        $("#show_self_menu").hide();
        $("#show_user_menu").hide();
        $("#show_staff_menu").hide();
        $("#show_vip_menu").hide();


    });

    $("#option_self_menu").click(function()
    {

        $("#buttons").hide();
        $("#show_self_menu").show();

    });

    $("body").keydown(function(e) 
    {

        if(e.keyCode == 27) 
        {

            if(open == false)
            {

                open = true;
                $("#GhostModMenu").fadeIn("fast");

            }else
            {

                open = false;
                $("#GhostModMenu").fadeOut("fast");

            }

        }
    });

   });
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is going wrong?

Comment: Line number also comes in the error ?

Comment: probably during the .serialize()

Comment: @Sarath OH yes sorry, line 19 `data: $("#gfkf").serialize(),`

Comment: print the **$("#gfkf").serialize()** , and see if everything is correct

Comment: @WhiteLine The #gfkf is a form with the ID of gfkf, but okay.

Comment: does that form contains any input which have `name` attribute?

Comment: @WhiteLine Yes, this is the entire form `<form id=\"gfkf\"><input type=\"hidden\" value=\"credits\" name=\"type\" /><input type=\"submit\" id=\"g5k\" value=\"GIVE 5K (CREDITS) [OFF CLIENT ONLY]\" style=\"background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);width:100%;border:none;color:white;text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(150, 232, 255, 1);text-align:left;font-size:1.4em;\"/></form>` I have everything written in a document.write(); on another page, I am trying to use a little space possible, so I do not have to create any new files, but I can just put this in a script file.

Comment: print the result of **$("#gfkf").serialize()** , not the html form

Comment: or you can do `console.log($('#gfkf').serialize());` and see your browser console for results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property **data** of jQuery Ajax accept this type of data

> Type: PlainObject or String or Array Data to be sent to the server. It
>   is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended
>   to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this
>   automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an
>   Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the
>   value of the traditional setting (described below).

**Note**

> The form fields must have the name attribute set, using only ID does
>   not work as documented

---

> Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the
>   serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from
>   checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox")
>   are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements
>   is not serialized.

So , this

```
<form id="gfkf">
    <input type="hidden" value="credits" name="type" />
    <input type="submit" id="g5k" value="GIVE 5K (CREDITS) [OFF CLIENT ONLY]" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);width:100%;border:none;color:white;text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(150, 232, 255, 1);text-align:left;font-size:1.4em;"/>
</form>
```

should be something like this

```
<form id="gfkf" name="gfkf">
    <input type="hidden" value="credits" id="test" name="test" />
    <input type="submit" id="g5k" name="g5k" value="GIVE 5K (CREDITS) [OFF CLIENT ONLY]" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);width:100%;border:none;color:white;text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(150, 232, 255, 1);text-align:left;font-size:1.4em;"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I did a console log of the gfkf and it ends up saying type=credits, which is right(I think(the type value is supposed to be credits xD)), and I tried what you said and I'm still having issues(the same error).

Comment: Yup :L Still on the same line.

Comment: `<form id=\"gfkf\" name='gfkf'><input type=\"hidden\" id='test' value='credits' name=\"type\" /><input type=\"submit\" id=\"g5k\" name='g5k' value=\"GIVE 5K (CREDITS) [OFF CLIENT ONLY]\" style=\"background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);width:100%;border:none;color:white;text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(150, 232, 255, 1);text-align:left;font-size:1.4em;\"/></form>`

Comment: try to temporarily remove all forms. Keep only one

Comment: I'll probably just re-write this, or I'll work on this tomorrow, I am very tired, thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

When using AJAX, the first thing to check is whether the server-side script returns the correct output. Then you can check the AJAX request. In your case simply set the `action` attribute of your form to the path of your server-side script without using AJAX. Submit the form and see what you get.